# Creating a DLL from libs without any new code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, managed-c++

I have a dll that uses managed c++ and consumes a native c++ library. This dll is then in turn consumed by a c# interface. As you probably guessed, the managed c++ is just interop code. Nothing in this is exported.

We have a new requirement that both the managed c++ and native c++ be accessed by an external c++ executable (for internal testing purposes). So I was thinking of changing the managed c++ layer to a lib, and have a separate project that creates the dll by consuming the managed and the native libs. There wouldn't be any new code in there. It's just a project that consumes the two libs. Then, we could have another project that also consumes these two libs and adds on top a bit of test code. But I'm having a great deal of difficulty in getting this to work. I cannot get the IDE to generate my dll. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a static link library from managed code, there's no support for it in the VS build system.  The unit of storage for managed code is an assembly.  They are not linked at build time, it happens at runtime.  Beware that your test program needs to be managed in order to test your wrapper.